# RGoogleMaps axes

Tags: r, axes, rgooglemaps

I can't find any documentation of the following problem I'm having with the axis labels in RGoogleMaps:

```
library(RgoogleMaps)
datas <- structure(list(LAT = c(37.875, 37.925, 37.775, 37.875, 37.875), 
                   LON = c(-122.225, -122.225, -122.075, -122.075, -122.025)), 
                   .Names = c("LAT", "LON"), class = "data.frame", 
                   row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L))
# Get bounding box.
boxt <- qbbox(lat = datas$LAT, lon = datas$LON)
MyMap <- GetMap.bbox(boxt$lonR, boxt$latR, destfile = "Arvin12Map.png", 
maptype = "mobile")
PlotOnStaticMap(MyMap, lat = datas$LAT, lon = datas$LON, 
                axes = TRUE, mar = rep(4, 4))
```

When I run this on my computer the horizontal axis ranges from 300W to 60E, but the ticks in between aren't linearly spaced (300W, 200W, 100W, 0, 100E, 160W, 60W).
Also, the vertical axis moves linearly from 300S to 300N.  It seems that no matter what data I supply for datas, the axes are always labeled this way.

My question is:
1. Does this problem occur on other machines using this code?
2. Does anyone have an explanation for it?
and
3. Can anybody suggest a way to get the correct axes labels (assuming these are "incorrect", but maybe i'm somehow misinterpreting the plot!)?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the code.  If you ignore the degree symbols, you will notice that the plot is labelled from -320 to +320 on both axis.  This is identical to the plot size (i.e. 640 by 640).  I haven't traced all of the code, but I suspect that the longitude and latitude is not passed to the axis labels.  You may wish to contact the package maintainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. As @Andrie suggested, this appears to be a bug. When `axes = TRUE`, the `degAxis()` function called by `PlotOnStaticMap()` extracts the x and y plot coordinates of the pretty tickmarks found by `axTicks()`. `degAxis()` expects these coords to be in the coordinate system of the map, but rGoogleMaps returns them as pixel coordinates, calculated from a central origin. With a plot size of 640 x 640, the pretty tickmarks are assigned to -300, -200, -100, 0,100, 200, 300 in both E-W and N-S directions. You end up with 300W, 200W, 100W, 0, 100E, 160W, 60W, because the `degreeLabelsEW()` function called by `degAxis()` assumes that, given longitudes must fall within [-180, 180], any longitudes higher than 180 are in fact in the western hemisphere (e.g. 200E is 20 degrees eastward into the western hemisphere, i.e. 160W). Not sure why it doesn't perform similarly with nonsensical N, S and W coordinates.
3. A quick workaround, continuing with your `MyMap` object:

   ```
   PlotOnStaticMap(MyMap, lat = datas$LAT, lon = datas$LON, 
                   axes = FALSE, mar = rep(4.5, 4))

   # x-axis
   xrange <- MyMap$BBOX$ur[2] - MyMap$BBOX$ll[2]
   xticklength <- xrange / (length(axTicks(1)) - 1)
   xticklabs <- seq(MyMap$BBOX$ll[2], MyMap$BBOX$ur[2], xticklength)
   xticklabs <- parse(text = paste(sprintf('%.2f', abs(xticklabs)), 
       ifelse(xticklabs < 0, '*degree*W', '*degree*E'), sep=''))
   axis(1, at=axTicks(1), xticklabs, cex.axis=0.8)

   # y-axis
   yrange <- MyMap$BBOX$ur[1] - MyMap$BBOX$ll[1]
   yticklength <- yrange / (length(axTicks(2)) - 1)
   yticklabs <- seq(MyMap$BBOX$ll[1], MyMap$BBOX$ur[1], yticklength)
   yticklabs <- parse(text = paste(sprintf('%.2f', abs(yticklabs)), 
       ifelse(yticklabs < 0, '*degree*S', '*degree*N'), sep=''))
   axis(2, at=axTicks(2), yticklabs, cex.axis=0.8, las=1)
   ```

Comment: I am long past needing this at this point, but this seems to be a viable work-around!  I think it could even be improved to some degree by messing with the plot margins so that the axis labels are actually outside of the map itself, but I do not have the motivation to work on this project any more.  Regardless, well-done, and hopefully someone else will find this useful!

Comment: Actually, I'm afraid my solution is incorrect... the coords used as tick labels are constant regardless of the specified `mar`. Sorry.